# Kendo grid filter text

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with filter option for a column which is a dropdown. I want to read the text which is been selected in the filter dropdown. Column dropdown shows text items for the user but it is binding to the grid with values for the text items.

When I try to read the filter options like this below:

```
var _grid = $("#demandgrid").data("kendoGrid");
var currFilterObj = _grid.dataSource.filter();

var currentFilters = currFilterObj.filters;

var FilterName = currentFilters[0].field;
FilterValue = currentFilters[0].value;
```

I see values instead of text. Meaning in the variable "FilterValue" I am getting value of columns dropdown instead of text in the dropdown.

I need to show this applied filter in a separate listview. Hence I am trying to retrieve the filter text.

Comment: Could you please provide column code, which has dropdown in filter?

Comment: info.ForeignKey(x => x.ReqTier2, Model.Tier2s, "Tier2Id", "Name").EditorTemplateName("Tier2Editor").Width(80).Filterable(true);         where "Tier2Editor" is a partial view in my mvc that has one kendo dropdown binded from db source. Please let me know if this is enough.